# Can't get spaces in paths correct in a Bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm stuck and could use some help with this batch script.
`%output%`gives the correct path even with spaces.
`%input%` gives me `Error: The file 'C:\Input' could not be opened for reading: open file error.`
The code is so similair, I don't understand why it reads one but not the other.
I've tryed with `"input=C:\Input folder\"` and `input="C:\Input folder\"` but still nothing.

I'm getting the folder paths thru jscript in a HTA file.

The code works great if I change the input to a folder without any space like `C:\Input\`

Thanks in advance.

```
@echo off & setlocal
set input=C:\Input folder\
set output=C:\Output folder\
set PATH=%PATH%;C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/

for %%a in (%input%*.mkv) do ( mkvmerge -q -o "%output%%%~na%%~xa" -s eng --title %%a "%%a"
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Warnings generated!
) else (
for %%b in (%output%*.mkv) do ( mkvpropedit -q "%output%%%~na%%~xa" --edit track:s1 --set flag-default=1
if errorlevel 1 (
echo %%~na%%~xa - Error!
) else (
echo %%~na%%~xa - Complete.
)
)
)
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

try with (in for you can separate elements with double quotes.Still the wildcard symbols will work):

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "input=C:\Input folder\"
set "output=C:\Output folder\"
set PATH=%PATH%;C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/

for %%a in ("%input%*.mkv") do (
    mkvmerge -q -o "%output%%%~na%%~xa" -s eng --title %%a "%%a" || (
        echo Warnings generated!
    ) && (
        for %%b in ("%output%*.mkv") do ( 
            mkvpropedit -q "%output%%%~na%%~xa" --edit track:s1 --set flag-default=1 || (
                echo %%~na%%~xa - Error!
            ) && (
                echo %%~na%%~xa - Complete.
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This however didn't fix the problem. It won't even execute the commands anymore.

Comment: I think this is one of those rare cases where you want the first `"` on the right of the `=`.

Comment: Nice to see you again @SomethingDark. It looks like it puts `" and '` in random locations in the error text. `Error: The file 'folder"Input -s eng --title "C:\Input' could not be opened for reading: open file error.`

Comment: @Jon - Try also removing the quotes from `"%input%*.mkv"` and `"%output%*.mkv"`. Worst case scenario, you'll just be where you started.

Comment: @SomethingDark - Thank you. Still not working tho. When I add  `Echo Executing from %input% to %output%` it shows the correct paths. I think I give up, I'll just have to use paths where there are no spaces. :(

Comment: I couldn't give up. Good thing, think there was some error with the mkvmerge commands itself.  Changed some stuff and use `("%input%*.mkv")` and leave the set input/output without `"`. Works fine now. Thanks for your time guys!